# Ms Access ReDim Multi-Dim array

Tags: ms-access, vba

What is the best practice to redim the first dimension of a multi-dim array?

The array would not be very big at all so I don't think a custom class DataType and Collection is warranted. The first dimension is likely to never go past 25 but I cannot be certain of that. However, the second dimension will always be two. (Rows~25, Columns=2)

I want the array to be dynamic because I do not know how many different categories the customer may add in the future.

I tried a SELECT DISTINCT on a union query of several datasets to get the category count ahead of time but due to the dynamics involved this did not return what I was looking for. There are too many cases to consider before adding the category to the list hence to dynamic array.

Comment: To my knowledge, the first dimension of an array can't be redimmed. I've had to do something similar, so I flipped the way I was storing the array, so in your case using the 2 as the first dimension since it is fixed, and redimming the second dimension. Then, when it came time to actually use the data, I flipped the array around so that the columns became rows and vice versa. Use `Redim Preserve arrayName(2, newDim)` to do this (preserve keyword keeps your data, without it the array is wiped out before increasing the size).

Comment: @RianBattle This is a great idea, but it hurt my head trying to think of how to do this. But I finally got it to work but I am not sure I like the solution. I have stepped away from the exercise and will look at it again with fresh eyes later.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just save the members of the array in a table and manipulate that with queries? Such a small dataset, there won't be noticeable speed penalties.